# Cant create initial liquidity in safemoon fork

Tags: ether, ethereumjs

Followed the initial steps provided at the openzeppelin community for adding initial liquidity to a pool but still, cant do step 2. here's the original answer which is not working - https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/cant-add-liquidity-on-pancakeswap-with-burnable-erc20-token/6993/10?u=tanishbaansal

Still getting the error at step 2 of the process

step1 done successfully - https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x422da9fab7f1a8d9099238e06ad57c291a2e2490fce6ba165ec9dd2fcee8d9e4

at step2 getting - ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.

[image]

Swapandliquifyenabled also set to false

Same Safemoon Fork with router address at testnet of pancakeswap at - 0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1

Token address - https://testnet.bscscan.com/token/0x37a30bc7565ce22126b55a572e133790b80fc49a

Answer (score 0):

The parameters `addLiquidityEth` and `amountETHMin` should be in wei units, you are passing in ether units. Remember 1 ether = 10^18 wei, you are missing 18 zeros. Also token parameteres should be in their minimal unit, if the token has 18 decimals and you wan to add 1000 tokens then you have to pass 1000 * 10^18 as parameter.